# Reading view when moving a finger across the screen

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

Please help, is it possible to do the next thing - am on the screen with your finger without lifting the last, and the program reads the view objects for which I spend.

Tried using onTouchListener, but there passed into the method onTouch always the view, which was touching.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy task. In your root view or in activity you should spy on all touch event. You can do this by overriding activity's dispatchTouchEvent method without braking super inmpementation. Just spy on events.

So we have events. Run a loop to recurcively find a view at event's coordinates (you can find several views). Do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contentViewCount; i++) {
    final View child = contentViews[i];
    child.getHitRect(frame);
    if (frame.contains(eventX, eventY) && child.getVisibility() == View.Visible) {
        if (child instanceOf ViewGroup) {
            // we found a view group and should run same loop on it's childs
        } else {
            // we found a view
        }
    }
}
```